# PhoneGap : Fetch Contact list with optimize speed

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

In Phonegap I try to fetch the contact list from phone.I need just name and phone number , its taking around 40 seconds to fetch all the result.I add the plugin in config.xml .In my phone I have around only 400 contacts. But when I alert the length of contact in **index.html** it says that 1351 list.I don't know where I am wrong.I think some optimization is needed while fetching name and number from phone.

advance Thanks...:)

**Config.xml**

```
 <feature name="Contacts">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.contacts.ContactManager" />
</feature>
```

**index.html**

```
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            var options = new ContactFindOptions();
            options.filter="";    
            options.multiple=true; 
            filter  = ["displayName", "phoneNumbers"];
            navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
        }

       var cSort = function(a, b) {
          aName = a.displayName ;
          bName = b.displayName ;
            return aName < bName ? -1 : (aName == bName ? 0 : 1);
            };

        function onSuccess(contacts) {              
            contacts = contacts.sort(cSort);
            alert("length " + contacts.length  );
            var i =0;       
            for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) 
            {
                console.log("Display Name = " + contacts[i].displayName);
                 if(contacts[i].displayName != null)
                 {
                    if( contacts[i].phoneNumbers == null )
                     continue;
                    else if(contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length)
                    {                           
                        for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++)
                         {
                          $('#contact_list').append('<li> Name:'+contacts[i].displayName+'</li>');
                          $('#contact_list').append('<li> Number:'+contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value+'</li><br><br>');
                        }
                        $('#contact_list').listview('refresh');
                    }
                 }
            }        
        }
        function onError(contactError) {
            alert('onError!');
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code from:

```
            {                           
                for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++)
                 {
                  $('#contact_list').append('<li> Name:'+contacts[i].displayName+'</li>');
                  $('#contact_list').append('<li> Number:'+contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value+'</li><br><br>');
                }
                $('#contact_list').listview('refresh');
            }
```

To:

```
                {
                    var finalList = '';
                    listEntryPoint = $('#contact_list');
                    for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++)
                     {
                        finalList += '<li> Name:'+contacts[i].displayName+'</li>' + '<li> Number:'+contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value+'</li><br><br>';
                    }
                    listEntryPoint.append(finalList);
                    listEntryPoint.listview('refresh');
                }
```

Comment: my doubt is where we declare the "listEntryPoint" . @JesseMonroy650

Comment: yes  I tried , but it still taking around 45 sec for getting full result. Around 25 sec is taking for fetching the list and 20 sec for sorting the list @ JesseMonroy650

Comment: @Binil, I don not know your data nor do I know your App. The next step is to limit the display. Only show as many thing that fit on the screen as you can, then print. Update the remainder later.

Comment: the app is just diplay the contact list in alphabetical order. Is there any good method for sorting the list

Comment: The contacts API has a filter built-in. This is the URL to your documentation: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.contacts

Comment: but the "filter " is using for search a particular name from the list. I need to display all the contact details in alphabetical order.

Comment: If you read the documentation, you will see that the API supports returning multiple records. That means ALL RECORDS too. The API does **NOT include sorting**. If you want to sort the records, you should build a sort function, or find a sort function. I do not have any support functions for ```contacts```.

Comment: yes, am using this function for sorting   cSort = function(a, b) {
          aName = a.displayName ;
          bName = b.displayName ;
            return aName < bName ? -1 : (aName == bName ? 0 : 1);
            };, but its take 30 sec for complete sorting

Comment: If that is the case, then only show as many record on the view as are visible. You can also pre-sort. That is, save the data sorted the way you want to display it. If a new item is added, then do an *insertion sort*.

Answer (score 0):

@BINIL S, you have a very expensive Jquery call:

```
$('#contact_list').append(...);
```

Change to:

```
listEntryPoint = $('#contact_list');
```

move that outside of the loop and assign it to a variable, that should help. You can also NOT insert the new entries one at at time. You CAN make the one large list before you insert into HTML. Like this,

```
finalList += '<li> Name:'+contacts[i].displayName+'</li>' + '<li> Number:'+contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value+'</li><br><br>';
```

After loop is done,

```
listEntryPoint.append(finalList);
```

That should help - Jesse

Comment: what is "listEntryPoint" @JesseMonroy650